# Why multiprocessing.Process don't initialize after empty queue?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I'm stucked with a question and i can't find a good answer.

I have a script who takes images from a folder and put then into a Queue who i named pool. In a **while true** loop i verify if there is images in folder. For yes, i take this images and put into this pool Queue, and so i create Processes who will run a function to verify if have faces on these images, and do others irrelevant things.

My question come to unusual comportament from the code. If in the folder have images, they distribute one image for each Process ant that's ok. but if have less images than Processes, or if the folder is empty, the processes are not been created when i put new images in folder.

There is any explication for this?

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
def face_search(pool, qtd_pool):
  # Do face recognition and move files
  # When files moved, the folder with images get empty until i put new images
  # if there's no face, the image is deleted from disk
  # At the end, it return True and enter in the next image loop

if __name__ == '__main__':
  #irrelevant stuff
  while true:
    pool_get = os.listdir(/some_directory/)
    qtd_pool = len(pool_get)
    pool = Queue()

    for image in pool_get:
      pool.put('/some_directory/'+image)

    # down below i create the Process, and join then when finished. They would be created for every loop, right? Why they don't act like that?
    procs = [Process(target = face_search, args=(pool, qtd_pool, )) for i in xrange(nthreads)]

    for p in procs: p.start()
    for p in procs: p.join()
```

Comment: Edit your Question with the `loop` condition inside `face_search` if any. Means does your process waiting until a new image is available or exit after image is processed?

Comment: It exit after image is processed. Than the while true loop make the same proccess to the next image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: ... the processes are not been created when i put new images in folder.

You do this **all** inside a `while` loop, without any condition if the folder is empty.
I assume you overload your System with new created Processes nothing to do.

Consider this approach, create your Processes **once** and let them waiting until a new image is ready.

```
def face_search(exit_process, job_queue):
    while not exit_process.is_set():
        try:
            job = job_queue.get_nowait()
            # Do image processing

        except queue.Empty:
            time.sleep(0.5)

    exit(0)

def process_images(job_queue):
    path = '.'
    for fname in os.listdir(path):
        job_queue.put(os.path.join(path, fname))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit_process = mp.Event()
    job_queue = mp.Manager().Queue()

    pool = []
    for n in range(mp.cpu_count()):
        p = mp.Process(target=face_search, args=(exit_process, job_queue))
        p.start()
        pool.append(p)
        time.sleep(0.1)

    process_images(job_queue)

    # Block until all jobs done
    while not job_queue.empty():
        time.sleep(1)

    # Stop Processes
    exit_process.set()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 and 2.7.9***